# how to get values of objects as array, given keys list?

Tags: javascript, performance, underscore.js, lodash

I have an object as follows,

```
obj = {
  '1': {val: 1},
  '2': {val: 2},
  '3': {val: 3},
  '4': {val: 4},
  ...
}
```

Given keys list(as an `Array`), I want to get all values list(as an `Array`).

For example,

If the keys list is `['3', '4']`, the output would be `[{val: 3}, {val: 4}]`

I tried as follows

```
_.values(_.pick(obj, ['3', '4']))
```

This works but it does two iterations. Is there any way to achieve the same in a single iteration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _.map(['3', '4'], key => obj[key])

Comment: RaR, are you aware that, under the hood, `_.values` and `_.pick` aren't anywhere close to `2` iterations? I'm guessing it's closer to `10`. Same for any lodash method you'd use in it's place.

Comment: @Cerbrus Is it? I was under the impression that it is optimised in such a way that it needs only one iteration to complete such operation. So I preferred lodash always :( I am guessing I have to look into source code before making use of any lodash methods.

Comment: @RaR, think of it this way: Lodash needs to take care of compatibility issues and all kinds of possible types of input values. In the end, it's all plain JS that's being executed, just with a bunch of extra stuff you really don't need. Lodash's appeal is in shorter, more readable code. But that doesn't make it perform faster ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something as simple as picking a few properties form a object, why not just use plain JS?

```js
const obj = {
  '1': { val: 1 },
  '2': { val: 2 },
  '3': { val: 3 },
  '4': { val: 4 }
}
const keys = ['1', '3'];
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  obj[keys[i]] && result.push(obj[keys[i]]);
}

console.log(result);
```

It doesn't get faster than that. Especially not with libraries like lodash, that need to iterate multiple times to cover all kinds of corner cases you're never going to have to bother with.

Or, even faster by storing the object access in a temporary variable, thanks to [@KoushikChatterjee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398764/koushik-chatterjee):

```js
const obj = {
  '1': { val: 1 },
  '2': { val: 2 },
  '3': { val: 3 },
  '4': { val: 4 }
}
const keys = ['1', '3'];
const result = [];
let temp;

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    (temp = obj[keys[i]]) && result.push(temp);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: very good solution, I appreciate +1 ^^, just assume if we can do something like `temp = obj[keys[i]] && result.push(temp)` then it would have been a bit more faster, as twice we are fetching  `by key from object` and `by index from array keys`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee: I like the idea, but that won't work: `let temp = obj[keys[i]] && result.push(temp);` -> `Uncaught ReferenceError: temp is not defined`. You wouldn't be able to access `temp`, because it's not declared when you try to push it. Using `var` instead of `let` doesn't throw an error, but still doesn't work properly.

Comment: No, declare temp outside for loop

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee: then the result is: `[undefined,1]`, similar to using `var`.

Comment: No no, I just wrote that on the fly, didn't  executes, just try this `(temp = obj[keys[i]]) && result.push(temp)` with a `(...)` when assigning otherwise  `&&` will execute first and then the `=` operator

Comment: Ah right, that works, and it's [actually faster](https://jsperf.com/picking-properties-functions-vs-loop) than my original code :D

Comment: heyy thanks for the edit, Actually the performance that was the main concern for this post, so was trying to tune the performance further sowhoever will come here will also get some performance efficient solution along with OP :)

Answer (score 5):

To create an array of values from selected object propsin Lodash use [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#at):

```js
var obj = {
  '1': {val: 1},
  '2': {val: 2},
  '3': {val: 3},
  '4': {val: 4}
};

var result = _.at(obj, ['3', '4']);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```